# HTML5 Canvas Collision Detection Confusion

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision-detection

I'm new to the site and coding.
I require assistance with my current javascript code and I am having trouble with my two objects being detected when colliding.

https://jsfiddle.net/ro5t3h5b/

Apologies for not being able to see the objects as they are png's.
If someone could help me specifically with this section so that the collision is detected, I would be very grateful.

```
function collision(a, b){

return  a.x < b.x + b.width &&
        a.x + a.width > b.x &&
        a.y < b.y + b.height &&
        a.y + a.height > b.width;
```

}

```
if (collision(player, asteroid)){
    player.playerImage = player.playerImage2;
    cancelAnimationFrame(animation_frame);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and then edit your question to conform with the site guidelines. Off-topic questions such as this one are routinely closed, but if edited to ask an *answerable* question, can be re-opened again. Thanks.

Comment: Very last line of collision ` a.y + a.height >b.width;` should be `b.height`? or to test if touching  ` return ! (a.x > b.x + b.width || a.x + a.width <  b.x || a.y > b.y + b.height || a.y + a.height <  b.y );`

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to detect collision:

```
var playerX = player.x + playerWidth / 2;
var playerY = player.y + playerHeight / 2;

var asteroidX = asteroid.x + asteroisWidth / 2;
var asteroidX = asteroid.y + asteroidHeight / 2;

var distanceX = (playerX - asteroidX)(playerX - asteroidX);
var distanceY = (playerY - asteroidY)(playerY - asteroidY);

var distance = Math.sqrt(distanceX + distanceY);

if(distance <= 0){
   console.log('Collided!');
}
```

if still a confusion watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYzA_kPWyJ8